# Firebase recyclerAdapter duplicate objects into arrayList

Tags: android

```
final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(Service.class, R.layout.browse_service_detail, ServiceHolder.class, mReference){               
       @Override 
       protected void populateViewHolder(ServiceHolder serviceHolder, Service service, int position) {

           serviceHolder.setServiceName(service.getName()); 
           serviceHolder.setInfo("От " + service.getPrice1());                          
           service.setQuantitySelected(service.getQuantityEnabled());

            if (Order.getInstance().getServices() != null) {
                for (Service serviceFromSingleton : Order.getInstance().getServices()) {
                    if (serviceFromSingleton.getName() == serviceHolder.getServiceName().getText().toString()) {
                        serviceHolder.getServiceName().setSelected(true);
                        serviceHolder.getServiceName().setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
                    }
                }
            }
            //add item to array
            servicesList.add(service);


        }
    }
};
```

**When I run this activity, it records the visible list objects to an array, but when I scroll down and go back up, it duplicates the first elements again into the array. How to fix it? For an item to be added only once.**

Comment: Use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `==` for compare two strings.

Comment: i'm asking why recyclerAdapter duplicating objects in arrayList?)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any issue in RecyclerAdapter..I think the list only inserting same data multiple times.
why not you check whether the list is empty or not before adding data into it and clear the data if its not empty and then add new.

```
if(servicesList.isEmpty())
   servicesList.add(service);

//else clear and add data
else{
    servicesList.clear();
    servicesList.add(service);
}
```

To handle data duplicacy, you can use a `Set` which will ignore duplicate inserts on scrolling.

```
servicesList.add(service);
Set<Service> mSet= new HashSet<Service>();
mSet.addAll(servicesList);
servicesList.clear();
servicesList.addAll(mSet);
```

OR use `Set` other than `ArrayList`

little clumsy but will work for you.

Comment: I need all objects from database to add into arrayList, my code adds only visible objects on recyclerView, and when I scroll down and then scroll up to back to added objects, it adds that objects again. Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't help me.